# Avoid file system cache during read/write to flash memory

Tags: linux, filesystems, file-management, cache

Is there a way to do kind of a direct i/o to the flash part on a portable consumer electronic device like iPhone etc. I want to do this to characterize the flash part performance and completely want to shut off / bypass file system cache. How can I do this?

Comment: Most disk benchmarking tools run in uncached mode by default, while others give the option.